# SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETFONTSMOOTHINGTYPE) return 0

Tags: c++, winapi

```
if (SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETFONTSMOOTHINGTYPE, 0, &uiType, 0) != 0) {      
  Debug(uiType); // shows 0
}
```

This happened to me on Remote desktop with Windows Server 2012 R2.
[According to the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947(v=vs.85).aspx) there are 2 possible values:

> The possible values are **FE_FONTSMOOTHINGSTANDARD** (1) and
>   **FE_FONTSMOOTHINGCLEARTYPE** (2).

I also found this similar question but no answers:
[Meaning of, SystemInformation.FontSmoothingType's return value](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d71b7ce7-f238-4ddb-897d-b1dac84373e7/meaning-of-systeminformationfontsmoothingtypes-return-value?forum=netfxbcl)

Does anyone knows what `uiType` 0 means?

---

EDIT: On that remote machine `SPI_GETFONTSMOOTHING` returns 0.

> Determines whether the font smoothing feature is enabled.

The docs are obviously wrong. I would *assume* the correct way should be to first check the `SPI_GETFONTSMOOTHING` and only then `SPI_GETFONTSMOOTHINGTYPE`

Comment: C# or C++ or Delphi? Pick one (preferably the one you're using)

Comment: What is the value of `SPI_SETFONTSMOOTHING` resp. `SPI_GETFONTSMOOTHING`?

Comment: Probably 0 corresponds to non anti aliased, and the docs are wrong.

Comment: @MaximilianKöstler, `SPI_GETFONTSMOOTHING` returns 0.

Comment: "On that remote machine" is surely the key phrase.  Anti-aliasing can significantly slow down a remote desktop viewer program, too many pixels that cannot be easily compressed.  Feature, not a bug.  This optimization can [normally be turned off](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742823(v=ws.11).aspx), ask at superuser.com if it is not RDC.

Comment: @HansPassant, I realize that the remote machine might be turning off Anti-aliasing. In that case it should have returned `FE_FONTSMOOTHINGSTANDARD` (maybe!). but still the docs should have mentioned a possibility of 0. i.e. "not supported". of even return 0 from `SystemParametersInfo` as failed...

Comment: Why do you suppose that "it should have returned `FE_FONTSMOOTHINGSTANDARD`"? ClearType is the *default* smoothing mode, and it is what you would get *if* smoothing was enabled. It isn't, of course, so the mode isn't relevant.

Comment: @CodyGray, On my XP with `SPI_GETFONTSMOOTHING` returning 1 as enabled, the default is `FE_FONTSMOOTHINGSTANDARD` (no changes made). so ClearType might be default on Vista+.

Comment: Right. The default on XP is "standard". Post-XP, it is "ClearType". I thought about mentioning it, but people have been telling me that XP is dead and buried. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The font smoothing "type" (`SPI_GETFONTSMOOTHINGTYPE`) is only meaningful if font smoothing is enabled (`SPI_GETFONTSMOOTHING`). The same is true for all of the other font smoothing attributes, like `SPI_GETFONTSMOOTHINGCONTRAST` and `SPI_GETFONTSMOOTHINGORIENTATION`.

You should check `SPI_GETFONTSMOOTHING` first. If it returns `TRUE` (non-zero), *then* you can query the other font smoothing attributes. If it returns `FALSE` (zero), then you are done. If you request the other font smoothing attributes, you will get meaningless noise.

So, in other words, your edit is correct, and the MSDN documentation could afford to be improved. I'm not sure it is "incorrect"; this seems like a pretty obvious design to me. It is a C API; calling it with the wrong parameters can be assumed to lead to wrong results.

[The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947.aspx) does say that the only possible return values for `SPI_GETFONTSMOOTHINGTYPE` are `FE_FONTSMOOTHINGSTANDARD` and `FE_FONTSMOOTHINGCLEARTYPE`, so it would not be possible for this parameter to indicate that font smoothing is *disabled* or *not applicable*. The current implementation of `SystemParametersInfo` might return 0 for the case where font smoothing is disabled, but since the documentation doesn't explicitly say that you can rely on that, you shouldn't rely on it.

Comment: Thanks. That make perfect sense to me.